# Change a method call in a private method

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

I'm currently migrating an old Hibernate tool from version 3.2 to the latest release. The way it works is that I'm inheriting from the *Configuration* class to a modified *AutofetchConfiguration* class. I've run into a situation where one of the methods that I need to override has been changed into a private method, making it impossible for me to override it.

This is how it was in the earlier release:

```
protected void add(XmlDocument metadataXml) throws MappingException {
    HbmBinder.bindRoot(metadataXml, createMappings(), Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
}
```

In this case it was that easy to make the change to call a different HbmBinder:

```
protected void add(XmlDocument metadataXml) throws MappingException {
    AutofetchHbmBinder.bindRoot(metadataXml, createMappings(), Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
}
```

In the version I'm currently working on, the bindRoot-call is called in this method:

```
private void processHbmXml(XmlDocument metadataXml, Set<String> entityNames) {
    try {
        HbmBinder.bindRoot(metadataXml, createMappings(), Collections.EMPTY_MAP, entityNames);
    } catch (MappingException me) {
        throw new InvalidMappingException(metadataXml.getOrigin().getType(), metadataXml.getOrigin().getName(), me);
    }

    for (String entityName : entityNames) {
        if (annotatedClassesByEntityNameMap.containsKey(entityName)) {
            annotatedClasses.remove(annotatedClassesByEntityNameMap.get(entityName));
            annotatedClassesByEntityNameMap.remove(entityName);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the method can't be overridden because of the private keyword. The method is using variables that I don't have in the subclass, so rewriting the public/protected methods that will call this method is not an option.

Is there something I can do in order to call AutofetchHbmBinder.bindRoot in this case?

Comment: I think your best option is to implement methods to retrieve the variables you need to rewrite this method independently.